# jQuery: why using xPath inside selectors?

Tags: jquery

They are faster or they are more flexible?

Worth to study them?

Thanks ;)

Comment: @can you ask with more details ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use xPath inside selectors. The support for that was dropped, in version 1.2 IIRC.

#### Edit:

There is however a [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/xpath) that adds basic xPath support to jQuery. However, I think that it's mostly intended for backward compatibility, i.e. if you already have a lot of code that uses xPath selectors.